# Do I need multiple visas when entering China for work and a vacation?

Tags: visas, china

I'm going to attend an academic conference in Shenzhen later this year. Since I've never been to China, I would like to combine the visit with some days of vacation there.

I need to apply for a Visa to enter China and I'm not sure whether I should get a tourist visa (L) or a non-commercial visa (F).

My main reason for traveling to China is the conference so I would guess the F visa would be the better match. However, I'm worried that the F visa will only be granted for the period of the conference and I would be unable to extend my stay any further. With a tourist visa that shouldn't be a problem.

Will I face any problems either way?

Answer (score 2):

For a conference combined with vacation a tourist visa is perfectly fine, the rules surrounding business visa and when they are needed changed on July 17 2019 but unless you are looking to actually work here it will not affect you.

There are many circumstances where you can apply visa on demand as well but you have to make sure you pass all the requirements.

We always recommend to have all visa related matters organized before traveling to China